# Sql wont run execute reader

Tags: sql, vb.net

I know that that `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ADOConnectionString")` gives the right location for my connection, and `family_id` is the number 6 (at `family_id=6` I know I have the right data in my `Product` table) so why won't this run past execute reader?

```
Dim sqlConnection1 As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ADOConnectionString"))
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
Dim reader As SqlDataReader
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [TID].[dbo].[Product] WHERE family_id=@family_id"
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@family_id", family_id)
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
sqlConnection1.Open()

reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
```

Answer (score 3):

You haven't attached the connection to your command.  One way to do that is:

```
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1
```

Another is to do it as part of the SqlCommand constructor:

```
    Dim sql As String
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand
    Dim reader As SqlDataReader
    sql = "SELECT * FROM [TID].[dbo].[Product] WHERE family_id=@family_id"

    cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlConnection1)
```